# What is use of let skView = view as! SKView

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to SpriteKit and see the code like `let skView = view as! SKView` so what is use of this? Also I am confused about the difference between `view` and `skView`, `scene` and `GameScene`?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }

  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
  }

}
```

Comment: What is "!" after as?

Comment: The things you are confused about are very basic (casting, variable names, classes). It seems to me like you are getting ahead of yourself and should start learning Swift by the basics.

Comment: I know its the casting view to SKView but what is use of "!" ?

Comment: The use of `?` and `!` in swift is foundational. Not understanding Optionals in Swift is like not understanding `&&` and `||` in C. If you don't know what `?` and `!` are, stop and read a book on Swift. Apple's Swift iBook would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

`as!` means "force cast". The value of `view` will be casted as `SKView`. If this fails, because `view` is `nil` or of a different type, the code will crash. That's why you should avoid using `as!` when you are not 100% sure of what type the value is.

---

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024775/4687348
- [Type Casting - The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's perfect.  what is relation between view and SKView?

Comment: Usually, the `view` property of an `UIViewController` is of type `UIView`. To edit some properties like `showsFPS` (which is only available in `SKView`, a subclass of `UIView`), you need to tell the compiler that in that case, `view` will be of the type `SKView`

Comment: Thanks. where can i know all these relations ? any book or place to talk about these?

Comment: You can find this information in the official [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/). For example: [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview) /// You can also see the full API Reference in Xcode: Window -> Documentation and API Reference

Comment: Thank you . That's exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Another question is that when i looked at he API is , what is relation between SKView ,SKScene,SKNode?

Comment: Sorry, but that's too much for a comment and I don't know much about SpriteKit. I would recommend you to read tutorials like [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners) about Sprite kit.

Answer (score 0):

`SKView` is a subclass of `UIView` that has additional capabilities for SpriteKit functionality. The `as!` operator is downcasting the view of `UIView` to a `SKView`, to enable using `SKView` specific functionality in `viewDidLoad()`.

Generally, the `as?` operator is recommended because it will gracefully fail to `nil` if it doesn't succeed, whereas `as!` will crash the app if the casting is unsuccessful. If you are 100% certain that you will always have the view is of type `SKView` in this case, then using `as!` can be an appropriate and less verbose choice.

For more information, I recommend reading this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637974/whats-the-difference-between-as-as-and-as) that compares the use of `as`, `as?`, and `as!`.

Comment: Can we allocate the object of SKView class instead of casting ? Maybe like  let skView = SKView ()

Comment: Yes we can instantiate skView = SKView(). But, the Storyboard hands us a view already. That view was not created programmatically by us so we just downcast it to utilize functionality from SKView class. Were we to instantiate our own SKView() object as you suggest then we would have to add it as a subview to the main view already given to us. There is is no way I know of to "convince" the storyboard to give us an SKView in the first place. I have tried editing the XML (right click storyboard file -> open as source) for fun. But there is no <skview> tag available.